# Can not rename folder in Vista (access denied)

Tags: windows-vista, permissions

I can't rename a folder from the command line or from explorer despite the fact that I am the owner of the folder (I have used takeown /f from the elevated command prompt and checked in explorer).

I've googled the problem but all answers seem to be related to ownership, which does not seem to affect this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to remove permissions from the parent. I would remove all permissions from the troublesome folder, then grant everyone full control over it and it's children - this should ensure you can rename it, and also that any odd permissions from the parent aren't being inherited.

1. Right click on the folder, and select properties
2. Select the security tab.
3. Click "Advanced"
4. Click "Change Permissions"
5. Untick "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent"
6. You'll be given a notice regarding permissions - Click "Remove"
7. The permissions area is now blank. Click Add
8. Type "Everyone" and click OK
9. Tick "Allow" next to full control.
10. Click OK
11. Back at the advanced window, you should only see "Everyone" now
12. Tick "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object."
13. You may also want to change the owner here.
14. Click Apply. When warned about the permissions being overwritten, click Yes.
15. OK your way back to Explorer.

You should be able to now make changes to the folder. You may also want to ensure the folder is not read only as this can sometimes happen (and the unset read only won't be kept until you make these changes to the permissions)

These instructions were written under Windows 7, but should be reasonably accurate under Vista. If you need more information or screenshots, let me know.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the folder or files in the folder are locked by a process. 
You also get this if you're in the folder in question in the command line.

You can use [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/index.htm) to see what processes have a specific file open. 
You could also try moving all files in the folder to a temporary folder to highlight the problem file. (if it is a problem file)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a local folder or a networked folder?

If local, try restarting your PC in safemode, in case it is another application that is holding onto the folder. Either way, check the security tab for permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UAC (User Account Control) turned on? If so, try turning it off, reboot the computer and then see if you can do it. I've seen UAC cause some very odd problems with regard to permissions even on an administrator account.