# Can't Delete Network Files or Folders

Tags: windows-vista, file-management

On my Vista system, I have some mapped drives that I would like to delete some files and folders from. However, if I delete something it goes away, but if I refresh the folder it will reappear.

Is this a common issue and is there a simple solution? I am using Vista Business without any service packs.

Answer (score 1):

While the exact symptom is slightly difffernt, the [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/29861/can-not-rename-folder-in-vista-access-denied/29866#29866) may just be the same:

Basically, you need to have write privileges to all the child objects in a given share.